# C++, Is is possible to declare an object with using the requiring it to be of a certain class?

Tags: c++, oop, object

First off I am new to C++, especially using C++ in an OOP fashion. I have a class with multiple subclasses, and I was wondering if I could ambiguously declare a variable to accept an object without limiting the which objects can be stored in it. I am asking because one of the multiple children will end up being used at a time. So if I cannot ambiguously declare a variable I a way to determine which of the numerous variables are in use.

Something along the lines of

`obj randomObj = new className;`

instead of

`className randomObj = new className`

Comment: Polymorphism; you can use a pointer to a the base type.

Comment: Look up inheritance and polymorphism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you're new to C++, and the syntax you use to describe what you want suggests you're more familiar with another languages like Java or C#. The syntax you show works fine in those languages:

```
Foo myFoo = new DerivedFoo;
```

This works because, behind the scenes in Java and C# `myFoo` actually behaves as a pointer to a Foo rather than as name for a fixed memory region capable of storing a Foo. In C++ the syntax `Foo myFoo` creates such a fixed memory region. Even if you try to put some derived type there by doing this:

```
DerivedFoo myDerivedFoo;
Foo myFoo = myDerivedFoo;
```

`myFoo` can still only hold a Foo object. Everything that's not a Foo is 'sliced' away during the initialization of `myFoo`, because it just doesn't fit in that fixed memory region..

So in C++ you have to explicitly do what Java and C# do behind the scenes by using C++'s pointer syntax:

```
    Foo *myFoo = new DerivedFoo;
```

Now `myFoo` is a pointer to a Foo, and that pointer can refer to a any `Foo` object, including the Foo parts of a DerivedFoo, without any slicing or anything occurring. `new DerivedFoo` creates a memory region where a DerivedFoo can exist, and then `myFoo` is set to point at the `Foo` part of the created `DerivedFoo`.

Answer (score 0):

Since all of the classes derive from a common base class, you can declare your variable to be that base class type, but still be able to assign any derived class to it, eg:

```
class BaseClass
{
...
};

class DerivedClass : public BaseClass
{
...
};

BaseClass *randomObj = new DerivedClass;
```

Answer (score 0):

A container can only consist of objects of the same type. If you want a heterogeneous collection, you need to stick a "handle" type into the container and access the object indirectly. The standard handle type is a *pointer*, and the standard construction is `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>>`, like this:

```
#include <memory>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

template <typename T, typename ...Args>
std::unique_ptr<T> make_unique(Args &&... args)
{
    return std::unique_ptr<T>(new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...)); // or "::new"
}

struct Base
{
     virtual ~Base() { }
};

struct Derived1 : Base { /* ... */ };
struct Derived2 : Base { /* ... */ };
struct Derived3 : Base { /* ... */ };

std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>> v;
```

**Usage:**

```
v.push_back(make_unique<Derived1>(true, 'a'));
v.push_back(make_unique<Derived2>(11, 22, 33));
v.push_back(make_unique<Derived3>("hello", "world"));
```